# Create custom Maven script to run other maven scripts in given order

Tags: maven, spring-boot

In gradle I can define task that runs other tasks in particular order, is it possible to do the same in maven?

For example, instead of running

```
mvn clean spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--spring.profiles.active=dev"
```

or

```
mvn clean spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--spring.profiles.active=prod"
```

I want to create single scripts like

`mvn server-run:dev` or `mvn server-run:prod` respectively

Answer (score 0):

In Maven, goals are executed in the order of build phases and then in the order the goals are defined in pom.xml.

You could attach different execution goals to same build phase and place them in certain order in pom.xml. You will need to add "execution" nodes to spring-boot plugin. Follow to further reading for inspiration: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html